# Gradient Vector Electric Potential.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

> If the electric potential in a point $(x,y)$ of the plan $xy$ is $V(x,y)$ so the electric intensity vector in point $(x,y)$ is $E = - \nabla V(x,y)$. Suppose $V(x,y)={e^{-2x}}{\cos2y}$
>
> Determine the electric intensity vector in $(\frac{\pi}{4},0)$
> Show that in each point of the plan, the electric potential decreases faster in the same direction and sense of the $E$ vector.

So I have this question, but I do not know how answer.

I have the Gradient: $\nabla E = ({2}{\cos(2y)}{e^{-2x}},{2{e^{-2x}}\sin(2y)}$

So show the eletric intensity vector in $(\frac{\pi}{4},0)$ is simple, just use the values, but i have no ideia of how demonstrate that eletric potential decress faster when in the same direction and sense of $E$ vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the gradient vector direction is the direction for which the function increase faster then since $E=-\nabla V$ we have that  the electric potential decreases faster in the same direction and sense of the E vector.

Refer also to [Maximum rate of increase- Directional derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2747468/505767).